# Use bing translator in my website

Tags: javascript, html, api, translation, bing

I recently have come across with a need for some type of "translation"-type that could translate specific text fields or areas to other languages.

I want when user will write texts in `**<input type="text" id="texttotranslate"/>**` html control and after space the text should get converted to local language **i.e. Hindi, Arabic  Finnish**

I am not sure if something like this even is out there - but I thought this might be a good place to ask.
**Link 1**
[I came accorss this links as well but i want it Javascript / ajax solution to get it done](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=357&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

**Link 2**
[I went through this and create my APPID](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis) 
 I am getting link 1 working in my C# console application but

i want a javascript solution for the same. ie. when i write a word in the text box it should get converted to local language i set .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Bing translator in your website, then there is no need to write any code in C#. You can use the Bing URL directly to translate the words.

Please refer to the following URL: http://basharkokash.com/post/Bing-Translator-for-developers.aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer. I found bing supports english to hindi translation  but dint get language code for **Hindi** as **AR** is for arbic...

Comment: link was broken

Comment: @Unknown Link was broken.

Comment: The link above is broken.  The correct link is here: https://basharkokash.com/2010/04/bing-translator-for-developers/amp/

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to put the Microsoft Translator widget on your site (http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget). Mark up the fields that you don't want translated using the class="notranslate" tag.

Alternatively, if you want to use the API, I recommend following the tutorials here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted1.aspx

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted2.aspx

While the second link does it in ASP.NET, instead of JavaScript, it should give you a rough idea for how to do it. At the very least I recommend getting your access token server side, using ASP.NET, PHP or something similar, so your Client ID and Client Secret are not in-the-clear on your site.

Finally, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512385.aspx, for the MSDN documentation on the AJAX API, including how to access it using JavaScript.